# Creating a new directory with new java.io.File() for FileDataStoreFactory(dir)

Tags: java, android

My MainActivity looks like the following:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
       b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                CalManager c = new CalManager(MainActivity.this);
                try{c.addEvent();}
                catch(IOException e){
                   Log.d("mychecks", "failed");
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Furthermore, my xml is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.user.test">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR"/>
    <uses-permission 
      android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

And I've got a problem with the following code in the CalManager-class:

```
public class CalManager {
    Context ctx;
    String dir;

    public CalManager(Context c){
        this.ctx = c;
        dir = ctx.getFilesDir().toString();
    }

    /** Directory to store user credentials for this application. */
    private static final java.io.File DATA_STORE_DIR = new java.io.File(
            dir , ".credentials/test");

    /** Global instance of the {@link FileDataStoreFactory}. */
    private static FileDataStoreFactory DATA_STORE_FACTORY;

    static {
        try {
            DATA_STORE_FACTORY = new FileDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_DIR);
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

The

```
DATA_STORE_FACTORY = new FileDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_DIR);
```

Statement throws the following error:

> 11-10 09:26:22.939 2374-2374/com.example.user.test W/System.err: java.io.IOException: unable to create directory: /.credentials/test

any ideas on how to fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This code does not compile. `dir` is an instance member and cannot be used in a static context..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Creating a new directory with `new java.io.File()`

Stop right there. Instantiating a `File` doesn't create a file on disk.

You need `DATA_STORE_DIR.mkdirs()` somewhere.

But you have another problem. `dir` is an instance member initialized but he constructor, so you can't use it in static code. You wil have to remove `static` from this `File` and the anonymous initializer block.

Comment: so how do I do that? simply adding this one before DATA_STORE_FACTORY = new FileDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_DIR);?

Comment: I waited 23 hour to reply to this to convince you that trying it for yourself is a lot more efficient than asking trivial questions here.

Comment: Ah sorry, and yeah, i made it work, thanks for your answer! At least it worked until the next error appeared...turned out, the google-API-quickstart "java" isn't suitable for android...So that the rest of the code doesn't make sense in this context. But thanks for your help in this case!